# Redis compound commands or command piping

Tags: redis

Been toying around with [redis](http://redis.io/) the past few days. Is it possible to run a compound command like the following:

```
MGET ZRANGE ranks 0 1
```

I have not found a definitive answer from the docs, [this old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/redis-db/1-x9-X2J7Ik), or from testing:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE ranks 0 1
1) "One"
2) "Two"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> MGET One Two
1) "1"
2) "2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> MGET ZRANGE ranks 0 1
1) (nil)
2) (nil)
3) (nil)
4) (nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

Redis' built in LUA scripting support should allow you to effectively chain commands together. See http://redis.io/commands/eval. Not exactly what you're looking for but perhaps this would be sufficient.

A simple example:

```
redis> set foo bar
OK
redis> set bar baz
OK
redis> eval "return      redis.call('get',redis.call('get','foo'))" 0
"baz"
```

Comment: Reviewed the link. Seems promising. However, could you provide an example based on my redis commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your command `MGET ZRANGE ranks 0 1` works because it gets the values of keys with names `"ZRANGE"`, `"ranks"`, `"0"`, and `"1"`. so you are getting four `(nil)` responses. There is no notion of a compound command in redis. Some clients support command pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one command with a Redis lua EVAL command like so:

```
EVAL 'local ids = redis.call("ZRANGE", "myset", 0, 100); 
return redis.call("MGET", unpack(ids));' 0
```

Best way for performance is to use keys and use cached script. Full instructions here:
http://redis.io/commands/eval